# RabbitMQ: Move a message to DLX when there are no queues in the original exchange

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm wondering whether it is possible to configure RabbitMQ to move a message to a DLX after it's been sitting in another (topic) exchange for a period of time without being delivered to any queue and consumed?

All examples I've seen require that a queue exist, because the DLX mapping must be declared on the queue. But what if there ***is no*** queue?

In my case, clients declare auto-delete queues that go away when the client closes the connection. This causes a problem for the publisher on the topic exchange, which is never notified that the message isn't likely to be consumed in the time allotted.

FWIW, I'm using RabbitMQ from C#.

**[UPDATE]**

I found an [article](https://www.compose.com/articles/configuring-rabbitmq-exchanges-queues-and-bindings-part-2/#alternateexchange) that seems to suggest I need to set up something called an **alternate exchange** in addition to a DLX, because DLX only receives messages that have already been routed. I'm currently trying to understand how it's supposed to work.

Further suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [alternate exchange docs article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html)

When declaring main exchange, you can provide the name of `alternate exchange` as parameter.

- Create the `alternate exhange` and make it of type `fanout`.
- Create a single durable queue bound to that alternate exchange.

Now all unrouted messages should end up in that queue.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed.